# How to display all the characters from a string in the component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and I used the `split()` to seperate the characters from the string. Down below is the code I tried

```
getBrandSortData(){
    let brandList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split("");
    <div>
        <ul>
            {brandList.map((item,index) => 
                <li key={index}>{item}</li>    
            )}
        </ul>
    </div>
    console.log(brandList)
}
```

Down below is the `render()`

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.getBrandSortData()}
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

I want to display all the characters in my component. How to display it as shown in

[image]

Comment: See [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for how to render a list of elements. Please try this on your own first and if you get stuck come back and update your question to include your [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with description of issue.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the question which I have tried

Comment: The image website can not open, please show us a new image.

Comment: You forgot to return the JSX from `getBrandSortData`. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getBrandSortData(){
  let brandList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split("");
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {brandList.map((item,index) => 
            <li key={index}>{item}</li>    
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>

 );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to `return`:

```
getBrandSortData(){
    let brandList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split("");
    <div>
        <ul>
            {brandList.map((item,index) => 
                <li key={index}>{item}</li>    
            )}
        </ul>
    </div>
    console.log(brandList)
}
```

second, it's invalid HTML to have `li` tags directly in a `div` tag. Place them into a `ul`:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.getBrandSortData()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```